# Implementing image redirecting with Vuex Store and Nuxt.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js

**Hi everybody i'm trying implement redirecting image from other domain to my domain.**
**But unfortunately it doesn't work, i hope that you could help me with that !)**

**Here's The Logic of this procces**:

I'm creating a new route page component on Nuxt.js. with name: like **/store**, then i'm need to set in the store my link to image like this: https://wallpapercave.com/wp/wp3663413.jpg. So now image in the store, and i should to redirect to this link in the store in my /store component so i put in my template binding to my route component like this

'/store' Component code:

```
fetch({store, redirect}) {
        redirect(store.state.app.icon)
      }
```

Component where i'm setting state and showing image in template

```
  fetch({app, store, route, nuxtState}) {
      return app.$axios.$get(`apps/${route.params.id}`)
        .then(res => {
          store.dispatch('setApp', {
            ...res
          })
        })
  }
```

templates:

```
<img :src="'/store'" :alt="$store.state.app.title">
```

***So i hope that somebody help me with this problem and say what i'm doing wrong !)***